# Adding a x tick but not the corresponding y tick

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm generating `pgf` plots on the fly and I would like to avoid adding non integer `y ticks` on my plots, while keeping all the `x ticks`. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[active, pdftex, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[{[]}]{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\begin{filecontents}{PJxpGrZtwos.tex.dat}
N      f             M
1024   3.407938e+01  25
1536   1.339487e+01  20
2048   1.139487e+01  19
3072   8.351236e+00  14
4049   6.466788e+00  13
6144   4.466788e+00  11
\end{filecontents}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfplotstableread{PJxpGrZtwos.tex.dat}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{N}\of{\loadedtable}
\let\relativeTo\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{f}\of{\loadedtable}
\let\f\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\f / \thisrow{f}}]{f-relative}\loadedtable
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[axis y line*=left, legend pos=south east,xlabel={N},xtick=data, xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{N},ytick=data, yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}, ylabel ={$\dfrac{f(\pgfmathprintnumber\relativeTo)}{f(N)}$}]
\addplot[black] table[x=N, y expr=\thisrow{N}/\relativeTo] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[blue, mark=*] table[x=N, y=f-relative] {\loadedtable};
\legend{{Linear progression},}
\end{loglogaxis}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[ymin = 5, ytick={10, 15, ..., 30}, ymax = 35, axis x line=none,ylabel={\# M}, axis x line=none, axis y line*=right, ylabel near ticks=right, yticklabel pos=right]
\addplot[red, dotted, mark=x, mark options={solid}] table[x=N, y=M] {\loadedtable};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I would like here is to have `\addplot[black] table[x=N, y expr=\thisrow{N}/\relativeTo] {\loadedtable};` not adding `y ticks` for non integer values of `\thisrow{N}/\relativeTo` while keeping all `x ticks`.

If you have any other way to draw a linear function from (x_min, 1) to (x_max, x_max/x_min), while having the nice corresponding `y ticks` (maybe by creating another table ?), that will also do the trick.

Keep in mind that this is for 'on the fly' plot generation, I don't know my value a priori, so I can't use in this case `y tick={1,...,6}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce some tolerance for the tick labels via some if conditions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents}{PJxpGrZtwos.tex.dat}
N      f             M
1024   3.407938e+01  25
1536   1.339487e+01  20
2048   1.139487e+01  19
3072   8.351236e+00  14
4049   6.466788e+00  13
6144   4.466788e+00  11
\end{filecontents}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfplotstableread{PJxpGrZtwos.tex.dat}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{N}\of{\loadedtable}
\let\relativeTo\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{f}\of{\loadedtable}
\let\f\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\f / \thisrow{f}}]{f-relative}\loadedtable
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
axis y line*=left, 
legend pos=south east,
xlabel={N},
xtick=data, 
xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{N},
ytick=data, 
yticklabel={
\pgfmathparse{abs(exp(\tick) - int(exp(\tick)))}
\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt>0.999 pt
    \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
\else
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<0.01 pt
    \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    \else{}
    \fi
\fi
}, 
ylabel ={$\dfrac{f(\pgfmathprintnumber\relativeTo)}{f(N)}$}]

\addplot[black] table[x=N, y expr=\thisrow{N}/\relativeTo] {\loadedtable};
\addplot[blue, mark=*] table[x=N, y=f-relative] {\loadedtable};
\legend{{Linear progression},}
\end{loglogaxis}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[ymin = 5, ytick={10, 15, ..., 30}, ymax = 35, axis x line=none,ylabel={\# M}, axis x line=none, axis y line*=right, ylabel near ticks=right, yticklabel pos=right]
\addplot[red, dotted, mark=x, mark options={solid}] table[x=N, y=M] {\loadedtable};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! Thanks. Do you know why neither
`yticklabel={
    \pgfmathifisint{exp(\tick)}{\pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}{}
}, ` nor `yticklabel={
    \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}{}
},` work ? (and by work I mean compile)

Comment: I think they are in the CVS version, right? Sorry, I did not have a look at the new additions yet. But even if it was working they will fail because the integer test is not reliable. That's why I've used tolerances.

Comment: They are in the version 1.6.1, released on the 23rd of August. And also, another question, how can I format the `x ticks label` ? Here, the `1000 sep` is clearly missing.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @BigDawg It's not working because they are not the actual numbers but only labels (since this is a logarithmic axis). If you wish you can use another `xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{...}}` etc.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution woked for me. Just delete the "ytick=data" part.
Have I misunderstood something?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[active, pdftex, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[{[]}]{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\begin{filecontents}{Dkb0rjC9L.tex.dat}
x y
1 1
2 1.5
3 2
4 3
5 4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick=data]
\addplot table {Dkb0rjC9L.tex.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph]

Comment: You can also pick specific ticks by using something like `ytick={1,...,4},`

Comment: Sorry, I over simplified the problem I was facing, I updated my first post, for which both solutions don't work.